# Python tkinter, ipad on grid only pads the right and bottom side

Tags: python, tkinter, padding, tkinter-layout

This is annoying lol.

```
frame_discord_session.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
frame_autoticket.grid(row=1, column=0, ipadx=50, ipady=50)
```

[image]

I tryed ipad with another widget just to make sure, and it works just fine with Button

```
btn_start_autoticket = CTkButton(
        frame_autoticket,
        text="Iniciar Autoticket",
        state=DISABLED,
        command=start_autoticket
    )
btn_start_autoticket.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=50, ipady=50)

frame_autoticket.grid(row=1, column=0, ipadx=50, ipady=50)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share how you create frame_discord_session?

Comment: @Ori i just did: frame_discord_session = CTkFrame(main)
Note: main is: main = CTkFrame(root)